# How do I get specific standard output from a batch script to be redirected into a text file

Tags: batch-file, exit-code

I have a function that sends files via psftp. After it sends off the data, I get the following output I get in the terminal:

```
Sent EOF Message
Server send command exit status 0
Disconnected: All channels closed
```

I need to take only the line that reads "Server send command exit status 0" echoed into a file. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know the pattern, could you just make a small program in `C++`, say that reads 3 lines and only outputs the center line? then feed the output from your original program using `|` operator on the command line

Comment: I'm a Linux/Bash guy. Not a Windows guy... What I would kill for grep command here...

Comment: Doesn't findstr require a filename? I need to capture a specific element from stdout

Answer (score 1):

```
yourcommand | findstr /L /c:"Server send command exit status" >yourdestinationfilename
```

Use `>>` in place of `>` to append rather than create anew, if desired.